# Load .php site in to div without reloading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reload

I am trying to create the following scenario:

A form in my index file collects input from a user, which is used to do some computation. The results of this computation should be echoed to him in a nice interface on the same page without reloading.

Currently, the results.php page is receiving the inputs correctly. Now, I just want to show it back inside the results div on the main page without reloading the results.php. .load is the wrong command for that. I need something like ".show"... Any ideas?

html:

```
<form action="results.php" method="post" class="ajaxform">
    //all the inputs
    <input type="submit" value="see your results" class="button"/>
</form>

<div id="results">
    //here he should see the results.php output
</div>
```

jQuery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

jQuery('.ajaxform').submit( function() {

    $.ajax({
        url     : $(this).attr('action'),
        type    : $(this).attr('method'),
        data    : $(this).serialize(),

        success : function( data ) {
                     alert('Form is successfully submitted');       

                    setTimeout(function() {
                     $('#results').load('results.php');  
                     }, 1000);

                  },
        error   : function(){
                     alert('Something wrong');
                  }
    });

    return false;
});});
```

Comment: Assuming the comunication is working, don't you just have to 'print' the returned value from `results.php` (`data`)?

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
$('#results').load('results.php');
```

To

```
$('#results').html(data);
```

if the returned results in `data` variable.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your problem correctly, *results.php* recieves the output you would show in the div *#result*. 
To use the return-data from ajax-request you have *data* as javascript variable. To show the result in the div you need the following statment in the success function from ajax-call.

```
$("#result").html(data);
```